# Issue updating modelbinding radio button in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, model-binding

I need help to get the last right in my form. It's a simple page where I have a question with some answers. One of the answers can be set to correct, this is not true always. But one question can only have one correct answer, so I use radio buttons. My initial modelbinding works fine, only the correct answer is selected. But when I choose another answer, my model don't get updated in the controller?

Here's my example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dnrn/tujaxx03/12/

This is my form:

```
<form name="questionForm" ng-controller="QuestionEditController as controller">
{{ hello }}
    <b>Spørgsmål:</b> <input ng-model="question.Question" name="questionText" type="text" size="100"/> <br/>
    <b>Spørgsmål Engelsk:</b> <input ng-model="question.EnglishQuestion" name="questionText" type="text" size="100" />

    <br />

    <b>Svarmuligheder:</b>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers">
        <b>Dansk</b> <input ng-model="answer.Answer" size="35" /> 
        <b>Englesk</b> <input ng-model="answer.EnglishAnswer" size="35" />
        <input ng-model="answer.IsCorrect" name="Correct" type="radio" ng-value="answer.IsCorrect" ng-click="setCorrectAnswer(answer.Id)" />
        <a href="">Slet</a>
    </div>       

    <input type="submit" value="Gem"/>
```

And my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('QuestionEditController', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.question = {
            "Id": 58, "Question": "Hvem opdagede Jupiters 4 måner Europa, Io, Ganyedes og Callisto?", "EnglishQuestion": "Who discovered Jupiter’s 4 moons: Europa, Io, Ganymede and Callisto?", "GermanQuestion": "", "Answers":
                [{ "Id": 130, "Answer": "Leonardo da Vinci i 1507", "EnglishAnswer": "Leonardo da Vinci in 1507", "GermanAnswer": "", "IsCorrect": false },
                    { "Id": 131, "Answer": "Tycho Brahe i 1599", "EnglishAnswer": "Tycho Brahe in 1599", "GermanAnswer": "", "IsCorrect": false },
                    { "Id": 132, "Answer": "Galileo Galilei i 1610", "EnglishAnswer": "Galileo Galilei in 1610", "GermanAnswer": "", "IsCorrect": true }],
            "AnswerCount": 0
        };

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.saved = $scope.question.Answers.filter(function (answer) {
            if (answer.IsCorrect) {
                return answer;
            }
        });
        };
}]);
```

Comment: make ng-model variable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is the filter and the way you are approaching the correct answer identification, and also a misuse of the radio button binding.

Please take a look at the `input[radio]` documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

It is recommended to store the selected value in a specific $scope variable, I forked your fiddle and came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bjhukmc4/

Please check if that is the desired behaviour and if I understood it well.

Basically I add a variable to the scope:
    `$scope.selectedAnswer = {};`

And then, set the radio buttons to store the selected value on that variable:

```
<input ng-model="$parent.selectedAnswer" name="Correct" type="radio" ng-value="answer" ng-click="setCorrectAnswer(answer.Id)" />
```

The `$parent` is needed because the  `ng-repeat` creates it´s own scope.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I should have read the documentation more careful before posting. It is indeed the desired behavior. In my real world example I fetch the data from a REST service, I can set  $scope.selectedAnswer to the correct answer when the json is returned. I just hoped I might be able to use one view model, but that's okay :)